# Make distro (one plain script) from bunch of Groovy classes

Tags: gradle, groovy, abstract-syntax-tree

I have a mixed devops environment: at first I develop the code using Idea/Groovy with traditional tools (junit for tests, gradle for ordinary distribution). I develop, test and so on; it works.

For some dedicated runtime I must pack all the groovy classes into one plain *.groovy file with the structure:

```
//here platform-specific imports
//it's constant-like list
import vendor.specific.dedicated.Vendor1
import vendor.specific.dedicated.Vendor2

//here my code-required imports which are needed for custom code
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
//..etc

//here custom classes developed by mine
@PossibleAnnotation
class BusinessLogic { int foo(int a){a+1} }
class SomeUtil {def bar(a){foo(a as int)} }

//here list of target Script's entry points required for the runtime
Vendor2 doWork(Vendor1 vendor1) {
    new Vendor2( BusinessLogic.foo(vendor1.intField1) )
}
```

So for the input, I have list of vendor-specific imports and some entrypoints.
For the output I have to create Groovy well-formed script.

What is the suitable method to do it?

Of course I could manually parse my *.groovy files but it's boring. Are AST or custom annotations helpers for that?

The ideal tool for me is some Gradle script.

Comment: is `cat boilderplate.groovy **/*.groovy > thescript.groovy` an option?

Comment: An option, but for the first I'd like to extract all the imports and to create distinct of it.

Comment: Well Groovy won't care about that.  You can have your imports all over the place and multiple import dont matter either.

Comment: Target script is not only for runtime but for other programmers at vendor side too.